# How can I either post or pass data from website to object element inside it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to pass data somehow from website to an object element which is contained inside it. 
A brief example:

This is a test1.html example which is in `https://domain.tld/folder1/test1.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

$( document ).ready ( function () {
   $("#templates").on("change", function () {
[.... here I want to pass data to object element ...]
      $("#test").show();
   });
}
);

</script>
</head>
<body>

<label>Open object </label>
<select id="templates name="templates">
<option value="1">Template1</option>
<option value="2">Template2</option>
<option value="3">Template3</option>
</select>
<div id="test" style="display: none;">
<object type="text/html" data="https://domain.tld/folder2/editor.php">
</object>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

test div element is opened full screen when select element is changed. I want to pass selected value to "https://domain.tld/folder2/editor.php" html code, because I need to make some custom details to it according to selected value. Is it possible?

Hope you can understand me.
Thank you so much for your help.
John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes it is, you can use AJAX :

```
var dataIn = { someKey : "someValue" };
$.ajax({
   url : "https://domain.tld/folder2/editor.php", 
   data : dataIn,
   success : function ( result ) {
        // do something with the response
   }
});
```

or `$.get` or `$.post` depending on what you need in your backend.

Comment: Hi Taki, great, it works!! thank you so much for you help!!

Comment: great ! glad i could help :) , mark the question as answered and my answer as correct :P